# What are these lock icons next to my Azure DevOps builds?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]

The lock icons are inside the red rectangle I drew. What are they? Do they mean that the builds are private and not accessible to anonymous users? If so, how do I make them public? Here is my build YAML:

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# Publish pipeline artifact
# Publish (upload) a file or directory as a named artifact for the current run
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/FrEee.WinForms/bin/release' 
    artifact: 'FrEee.WinForms'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  continueOnError: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are they? Do they mean that the builds are private and not
>   accessible to anonymous users?

The `lock` icons are used to indicate that the history of one build pipeline is retained.

See:

[image]

By default, these histories(*histories of the build pipeline I once ran*) above will be deleted after 30days. If we retain them, these histories won't be deleted and will always be kept.

> And why would my three most recent builds get this status?

By default, devops will lock the 3 most recent **successful**(Succeed + Succeed with warnings) builds.

You can control this behavior in `Project Settings => Settings`:

[image]

For example, change the `Number of runs...` from 3 to 1 and then only one most recent build will be retained automatically. (**Failed run won't be locked!**)

> Also, if I right click a retained build, it gives me an option to
>   retain it, not to stop retaining it - what's going on here?

Agree with **Jessica**, your build must be retained by release. There's several situations to display the icon:

1. Run a single build pipeline, and this is a successfully one which is also most recent. Then the run will be automatically locked. (See above)

In this situation, right-click the build you'll see: `stop retaining it`.

2. Manually retain the run though it's not most recent.

In this situation, right-click the build you'll also see: `stop retaining it`.

3. Retained by release. When we create a release pipeline, we can set a build pipeline as the source of Artifact when configuring that, see:

[image]

In this situation, the build is retained by release. Right-click the build you'll see `Retain build`.

Hope all above helps to resolve your issue. If I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me :)

Answer (score 1):

The lock means that this is a retained build. You can release it by clicking "Release" in the right-click menu.

Comment: In case you have already deleted the owning pipeline or are not able to release via UI - ehich does happen with Azure from time to time, you can release it via REST api also.

Comment: Thanks! But what is a "retained" build? And why would my three most recent builds get this status?

Comment: Also, if I right click a retained build, it gives me an option to retain it, not to stop retaining it - what's going on here?

Comment: @ekolis Agree with Aman, just not only retained manually. **retained by release** can also show this icon. According to your description, I think your build must relevant with one release and it is retained by a release.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops for more details